# Why aren't my ports opening on my UBNT airrouter?

Tags: networking, router

I'm trying to start running a server at home and I've setup the ports on the router like this: internal IP: *192.168.1.111* internal port: *UDP 9987* external Port: *9987* source and external IP/mask: *0.0.0.0/0*

The port is used for a teamspeak 3 server. the router mode is SOHO router. I do have a static IP set on the machine.

Comment: have you confirmed that you have a service on that port on the internal host, and that it is listening on an IP other than localhost? Linux: `sudo netstat -ntlup | grep 9987`  
Windows (powershell as Admin): `netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING | findstr 9987`. Make sure the IP displayed is either 0.0.0.0:0 or 192.168.1.11, and not anything in 127.0.0.0/8.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup seems correct. Outside of that there are three main points worth investigating:

1. Is there a service listening on port 9987? I gather you're setting up a teamspeak server, so ensure that one is up and running
2. Is there a firewall running? If so, you may need to add a rule to open port 9987.
3. Are you sure only UDP is required, and not TCP as well?

A handy tool to see if port forwarding and everything in between is set up correctly: http://canyouseeme.org/ . Just enter your IP and the target port, and the website will report back the results.